# Kernel error with Anaconda (Python 2.7) for Windows 10. Spyder IDE console error

Tags: python, python-2.7, kernel, anaconda, spyder

I installed free Python distribution **Anaconda** from here:
[*https://www.continuum.io/downloads*](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

My OS: **Windows 10 64-bit**.
I downloaded Anaconda for Windows 64-bit with **Python 2.7**.

---

When I start **Spyder IDE** in **IPython console** window I see some error with the header:

> *An error ocurred while starting the kernel*

It looks like this:
[image]

In the end of the error log shown above I see the following lines:

```
 [IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
 [IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Could not decode 'C:\\Users\\\xc0\xe4\xec\xe8\xed\xe8\xf1\xf2\xf0\xe0\xf2\xee\xf0\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime' for unicode trait 'connection_dir' of an IPKernelApp instance.
```

In **Console** window and **Kernel** tab I can see the same error message:
[image]

---

It is the 2-nd time I am installing this distribution. In the 1-st time I had installed **Anaconda** on **Windows 8** and it worked just fine without any problems. I just installed it and could use it instantly. For now, I am trying to use it on **Windows 10** and such errors occured. How to resolve it?

Comment: For jupyter but probably relevant https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub/issues/444

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Anaconda doesn't properly install when the installation folder contains unicode characters, which is your case:

```
C:\\Users\\\xc0\xe4\xec\xe8\xed\xe8\xf1\xf2\xf0\xe0\xf2\xee\xf0\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime
```

So one solution to solve your issue would be to install Anaconda in a folder where the path contains only ASCII characters:

```
C:\Python\Anaconda
```

Comment: My username is "Администратор". So my folder in Users folder named "Администратор". I installed Anaconda to C:\Python\Anaconda, but anyway the installator installed some stuff to Users\Администратор folder and it does not work when I launch Spyder IDE.

Comment: Have you tried to install with "Run as administrator" from the context menu?

Answer (score 3):

Go into your Windows environment variables (just type `path` in the Windows search bar and hit `enter`).  Click `New`, type in `IPYTHONDIR` as the `Variable name` and put the directory of your iPython installation (your working directory, such as `C:\Users\username\.ipython\`) in the `Variable value` field.  Try to launch iPython again.

Note Python 2.x requires unicode so you may have to put the directory as `u'c:\anaconda3\'` etc. so it reads it as unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is add environmental variable JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR points to existing directory